# Scrolling through two columns and viewing the differences and remove duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I use the code below to remove the duplicates from the xcol (first selected column) depending on the second column. With 2 for loops I am checking if 2 cells from column 1 and 2 cells from column 2 are identical and ONLY then remove the duplicated cell from column 1. My code removes all data, no matter if there are or not duplicates. Any idea why? Thanks.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xCol As Long
    Dim x2Row As Long
    Dim x2Col As Long
    Dim xrg As Range
    Dim xrg2 As Range
    Dim xl As Long
    Dim x2 As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xrg = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", _
                                    ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)

    Set xrg2 = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", _
                                    ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)

    xRow = xrg.Rows.Count + xrg.Row - 1
    x2Row = xrg2.Rows.Count + xrg2.Row - 1
    xCol = xrg.Column
    x2Col = xrg2.Column
    'MsgBox xRow & ":" & xCol
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For x2 = x2Row To 2 Step -1
        For xl = xRow To 2 Step -1
            If ((Cells(xl, Col) = Cells(xl - 1, xCol)) And (Cells(x2, x2Col) = Cells(x2 - 1, x2Col))) Then
                Cells(xl, xCol) = ""
            End If
        Next xl
    Next x2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

An example:

Before:

```
Group  ID 
2010   16
2010   16
2010   15
2012   15
```

After (how it should be)

```
Group  ID 
2010   16
2010  
2010   15
2012   15
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur. If you cannot see the errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work. Remove that line and fix your errors before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

In your "if" line exchange Col with xCol!
Use "Option Explicit" to avoid these kind of errors!

```
For x2 = x2Row To 2 Step -1
    For xl = xRow To 2 Step -1
        If ((Cells(xl, Col) = ...
```

After the correction of this mistake your code does the following compares (which I believe is not what you want to do):

```
x2 xl   Compare 1   Compare2 
5  5    B5=B4       A5=A4
5  4    B4=B3       A5=A4
5  3    B3=B2       A5=A4
5  2    B2=B1       A5=A4
4  5    B5=B4       A4=A3   => DELETE
4  4    B4=B3       A4=A3
4  3    B3=B2       A4=A3   => DELETE
4  2    B2=B1       A4=A3
3  5    B5=B4       A3=A2
3  4    B4=B3       A3=A2
3  3    B3=B2       A3=A2
3  2    B2=B1       A3=A2
2  5    B5=B4       A2=A1
2  4    B4=B3       A2=A1
2  3    B3=B2       A2=A1
2  2    B2=B1       A2=A1
```

To print the compared addresses I have added the following lines:

```
        If ((Cells(xl, xCol) = Cells(xl - 1, xCol)) And (Cells(x2, x2Col) = Cells(x2 - 1, x2Col))) Then
            Debug.Print x2; xl; Cells(xl, xCol).Address; "="; Cells(xl - 1, xCol).Address, Cells(x2, x2Col).Address; "="; Cells(x2 - 1, x2Col).Address; "=> DELETE"
            Cells(xl, xCol) = ""
        Else
            Debug.Print x2; xl; Cells(xl, xCol).Address; "="; Cells(xl - 1, xCol).Address, Cells(x2, x2Col).Address; "="; Cells(x2 - 1, x2Col).Address
        End If
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, is not what I want to do. My code compares all values from all rows, but I want is to compare 2 cells (for ex. A5=A4 .. the same for B), if there are duplicates remove the value from cell x1, after "go ahead and forget these values" (compare the next two)

Comment: Just take the above table and correct it as you want to have it. Then you have the references as you want them and you are done!